# Create two endpoints with the same private port on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-connect

I have an apache server running on port 8080.
I've created this endpoint:

> 8080 forwarding to 8080

But when I try to create this:

> 80 forwarding to 8080

I get an error that says that the private port and protocol conflict with another endpoint.
How can I have two endpoints forwarding to the same private port?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you're using Cloud Services (web/worker) or Virtual Machines? Also: Not sure why you tagged this as Azure Connect; this has nothing to do with Connect.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported.  If you think this functionality is important, there is a uservoice suggestion that you can vote on here: http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role-/suggestions/3001519-endpoints-should-allow-reuse-of-private-ports

Comment: Updated link: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role/suggestions/3001519-endpoints-should-allow-reuse-of-private-ports

Comment: Until they add this feature, I was able to sucessfully use this utility on my Server 2008R2 system to setup a port translation. In Azure, I configured endpoint 80 to 80 and then 8080 to 1234 (don't forget to open port 1234 on your Windows firewall!). Then using this utility, I configured port 1234 to forward to 80. Just make sure you run as admin and follow the README, as noted in one of the comments on the SourceForge page.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/